# Been to last stage interview and have no idea of salary

Tags: salary, negotiation

I interviewed with a company. All went very well and people I met felt very positive about me. It's a medium company which has just been bought by a large group.
The question of salary has never been raised until briefly on the last round interview where they haven't been able to tell me what they could offer, even a range. They instead ask me to send what my actual package is ( salary, holidays etc..) and they will then write an offer( which is fantastic!) but weird.
I am actually expecting a significant salary increase ( 10k), I am wondering If I should just tell them what am I on and wait for their offer before negotiating?
Or, if I should not say what am I on and say my target instead?
I did some research on the market, so I have an idea of what the market is offering but don't have a clue about what they can offer. I really want to the job. 
What do you advise?

Comment: Never disclose your current salary.  Give them what salary range you are prepared to live with, and then start the negotiations from there.

Comment: Everything that can be said here can be or has been said on the linked question, confirming duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe people consider disclosing current salary. Never do this! Don't tell recruiters. Don't tell potential new employers. All you have to say is, "I'd prefer not to disclose my current salary".

The only people that have any right to that information are your spouse and the IRS. You could be about to be offered double your current salary! Why would you shoot yourself in the foot?! Wait for their offer, then (unless it blows you away) say hmm, you were hoping for more and ask for a few days to think about it. Where you go from there depends on your analysis of the whole offer.

Answer (score 0):

Every time I have ever moved jobs, I have always talked about my current salary and benefits package and my expectations of salary and package at the new role. Sometimes that has been an agreed decrease in salary, because other conditions benefit me, and sometimes it has been an agreed increase. In fact, I have never understood why people treat the whole salary negotiation thing as a game against an enemy - it's both parties trying to get to an agreed point, and having info in up front gets you there faster and saves time if the expectations are obviously not going to match.

Either way, it leaves everything above board and gives me a good starting position to discuss what I need and why. If the company doesn't feel like my expectations are appropriate for them, it is very simple to then step away from the conversation and look elsewhere.

So tell them what you expect, what you are on, and the reason for the increase (experience, specific skills, etc.)